# error with add method in the header file in C++

Tags: c++, vector, header, addition

Hey i have a vector in a header file(Inventory.h) along with a cpp(Inventory.cpp) file for the header file(Inventory.h).  I cant figure out how to use the push and pop functions without creating a seperate function called add that looks like this.

```
vector<string>s Inventory ::add(string item)
{
inventory.push_back(item);
return item;
}
```

But doing this shows me an error:

```
Error   1   error C2511: 'void Inventory::add(std::string)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Inventory'   c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.cpp 19  1   MaroonedCA2
```

Here is my Inventory.h

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H


class Inventory
{
public:
    //Constructor
    Inventory();

    //Methods.
    string add();
    void displayInventory();
    void showInventory();
private:
    //Data members
    };


#endif //INVENTORY_H
```

And my Inventory.cpp.

```
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   //  To enable the use of the vector class.
#include <string>


using namespace std;
vector<string> inventory;
vector<string>::iterator myIterator;
vector<string>::const_iterator iter;


Inventory::Inventory()
{

}

vector<string>s Inventory ::add(string item)
{
inventory.push_back(item);
return item;
}

void Inventory:: showInventory()
{
char input[80];
    cin >> input;
    char inventoryRequest[] = "i";
    int invent = strcmp (input,inventoryRequest);
    //compare the player input to inventoryRequest (i) to see if they want to look at inventory.
    if(invent == 0)
    {
        displayInventory();
    }


}
void Inventory:: displayInventory()
{
//vector<string> inventory;
    cout<< "You have " << inventory.size() << " items.\n";
    cout << "\n******Inventory******";
    cout<< "\nYour items:\n";
    for (int i= 0; i< inventory.size(); ++i)
        cout<< inventory[i] << endl;
}
```

If i could get help with this function or a solution to using the push/pop in my main whilst in the header file it would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: New Errors.

```
Error   1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'add' c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   17  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   17  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   3   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string' c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   17  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   5   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'add' c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   17  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   6   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   17  1   MaroonedCA2
Error   7   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string' c:\users\conor\documents\college\dkit - year 2 - repeat\dkit - year 2 - semester 1 - repeat\games programming\maroonedca2\maroonedca2\inventory.h   17  1   MaroonedCA2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure your **.h** and **.cpp** methods match

**.h**

> `string add(string item);`

**.cpp**

> `string Inventory::add(string item)`

It says overloaded function not found because you're trying to call a function you did not define in your header.

Comment: Did you replace the ones you had? Or did you just add these

Comment: I replaced the ones i had.  They are now identical to yours.

Comment: Have you included the <string> library?

Comment: ye i just found it but it didnt replace the errors.  I will add the errors in my post.7

Comment: Error 1, it says exactly what the error is and where it occurs. I think you can solve this yourself ;)

Comment: Im sorry but i dont know what syntax would be missing before it :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19910/discussion-between-pendo826-and-tim)

Answer (score 2):

It seems the declaration of `add()` and its implementation use different signatures:

```
class Inventory
{
public:
    // ...
    string add();
};

vector<string>s Inventory ::add(string item)
{
    // ...
}
```

where the extra 's' after `vector<string>` seems to be entirely out of place anyway.

Comment: s would be the funtion name, am I right? But I doubt he wants this function to return a vector of strings

Comment: No i dont sorry that was just playin with code to see what would work and what wouldnt.

Comment: Given that a qualified name comes right after the `s`, it is just an error.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that. Anyway, usually when you make a method called  "add" or "delete" you give it a boolean return type so you can check whether or not it performed the action right.

Comment: @Pendo826: Well, the code you posted certainly has the problem that the function declaration and the definition mismatch as listed above. The error message states that you actually used yet another version. You might want to post the code you actually have problems with...

Comment: first of all i found that i didnt include string in the header file.